# Urls config in django-registration in Django

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am newbie Django dev, I have a bit problem about urls config. I want to make url http://localhost:8000/user-auth/register/
In my project, there is user_auth app with below urls:

```
 from django.conf.urls import url     
    from . import views     
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^register$', views.register),
    ]
```

In register this url within urls in my site:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^user-auth/', include('user_auth.urls')),        
]
```

In my view user_auth/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse
from .forms import RegisterForm

def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        response = HttpResponse()
        response.write("<h1>Thanks for registering</h1></br>")
        response.write("Your username:" + request.POST['username'])
        response.write("Your email" + request.POST['email'])
        return response
    registerForm = RegisterForm()
    return render(request, 'user_auth/register.html', {'form':registerForm})
```

In my user_auth/forms.py

```
from django import forms

class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(label='Username', max_length=100)
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    email    = forms.EmailField(label='Email')
```

When I access to the link http://localhost:8000/user-auth/register/, the console announce "Not Found: /user-auth/register/". I dont know reason why and where. Could you please help me on this problem?. Tks

Comment: have you tried the same by removing trailing slash "http://localhost:8000/user-auth/register"

Comment: oh oh, thank you so much, I have just removed slash end of urls and it worked well.